# Variable type List<string> In object, how can I make a List of this object

Tags: c#

I know it may be a simple question, but I could't find anything because I didn't know how to search for it.

I have an object called 'ValidDay':

```
 public class ValidDay
    {
        public string Day { set; get; }
        public List<string> Time { set; get; }
    }
```

In which I have a string List.

On my main code I want to make a List of this object like so:

```
List<ValidDay> list2 = new List<ValidDay>();
List<string> hours = new List<string>();

while (condition)
{
    hours.Add(date.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
}

  list2 = new ValidDay()
  {
    Day = "Monday",
    Time = hours
   };
```

But I get a "cannot implicitly convert type " error.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `list2.Add`...?

Comment: You have to `Add()` the item to the list.  You already do that in your `while` loop so I am not entirely sure what you are asking...

Comment: On what line does the error occur? What is the exact error message? What should that code do?

Comment: You've already instantiated `list2` as a `List` of `ValidDay` type.  You can't just make it a singular `ValidDay` after that.  You need to `.Add` to the `List` in `list2` if I am reading your error correct.

Comment: You define `list2` as a `List<ValidDay>` but then you're trying to make a new `ValidDay` out of it and not add it to the list `list2 = new ValidDay()`. Do `list2.Add(new ValidDay{Day = "Monday", Time = hours});`

Comment: As a code review note: consider using `System.DayOfWeek` as the type for your `Day`.  Having a `List<string>` named `hours` or `Time` is confusing.  Consider using the `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, `DayOfWeek`, etc. types for the purposes they were created for.  They are pretty good at keeping track of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list2` is a list:

```
List<ValidDay> list2 = new List<ValidDay>();
```

But you're trying to set an object to it:

```
list2 = new ValidDay() { /.../ };
```

Don't *set it* to an object, simply *add* the object to it:

```
list2.Add(new ValidDay() { /.../ });
```

Comment: Though OP seems to know how to fill a list since he has `hours.Add(date.ToString("hh:mm tt"));` in his code...

Answer (score 0):

`list2` is a `List<ValidDay>` and can thus only be set to a `List<ValidDay>`. So it's either this:

```
list2 = new List<ValidDay>
{   
    new ValidDay()
    {
        Day = "Monday",
        Time = hours
    }
};
```

...or change the type (and name) of `list2` to `ValidDay`.

You are currently trying to set `list2` to a `ValidDay` and not a `List<ValidDay>`.

By the way, as pointed out by @David, there is no point creating an empty list before you assign the `list2` variable. Remove new `List<ValidDay>()` or create the list after the `while` loop.

```
List<ValidDay> list2;
```

Comment: It's worth noting here that the initially created list is no longer needed if one is going to overwrite it with a new list.  Might as well remove it from the declaration line.